# How do I get the first element in a rolling window on Pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I have the following data structure:
[image]

and what I'd like to do is for each location, date to determine what was the spending exactly n days ago.

I am trying with a rolling window here but for some reason, when I create the window, I don't know how to get the first element in it:

```
dummy_data["spending_3_days_ago"] = (
        dummy_data.sort_values("date")
        .groupby("location")["spendings"]
        .transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).??first??())
    )
```

I can call all type of aggregate functions on the window such as: sum, mean etc. but I can not get the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `rolling` but rather a [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
dummy_data["spending_3_days_ago"] = (
        dummy_data.sort_values("date")
        .groupby("location")["spendings"]
        .shift(3)
    )
```

Output:

```
   location        date  spendings  spending_3_days_ago
0      1122  2017-12-01     451.12                  NaN
1      1122  2017-12-02     542.43                  NaN
2      1122  2017-12-03     512.23                  NaN
3      1122  2017-12-04     821.23               451.12
4      2233  2017-12-01     892.31                  NaN
5      2233  2017-12-02     303.32                  NaN
6      2233  2017-12-03     673.32                  NaN
7      2233  2017-12-04    1238.32               892.31
```

Or, if you want to simulate `min_periods=1`, backpropagate the values:

```
dummy_data["spending_3_days_ago"] = (
        dummy_data.sort_values("date")
        .groupby("location")["spendings"]
        .apply(lambda g: g.shift(3).bfill())
    )
```

Output:

```
   location        date  spendings  spending_3_days_ago
0      1122  2017-12-01     451.12               451.12
1      1122  2017-12-02     542.43               451.12
2      1122  2017-12-03     512.23               451.12
3      1122  2017-12-04     821.23               451.12
4      2233  2017-12-01     892.31               892.31
5      2233  2017-12-02     303.32               892.31
6      2233  2017-12-03     673.32               892.31
7      2233  2017-12-04    1238.32               892.31
```